# How to run teamviewer 11 on Ubuntu - install completed

Tags: teamviewer

I'm very new to Ubuntu 14.04 and want to install and run Teamviewer on my PC.
I have to maintain someone else's PC in another country who has Ubuntu installed.
I've installed it from the "Files and Folders" but can't find the application saved anywhere. 
I've followed the instructions give by others to install and it seemed to work.

Where do I look for the teamviewer application and how to I run it?
Thank you

Comment: My TeamViewer is installed in `/usr/bin/` as `/usr/bin/teamviewer`. You can navigate there and just double click and choose "Run". It'll start up. If this does not work tell us the details on how you installed the program. Also, if you'd open up your terminal an type in `which terminal` it'd tell you where it's installed (if it's installed).
EDIT: In case you don't realize this, but you don't have to run Ubuntu to maintain it elsewhere via TeamViewer.

Answer (score 3):

run:

```
sudo teamviewer --daemon enable
```

and then open teamviewer from the GUI

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed TeamViewer, by downloading the `'*.deb'` file from their website, then it should be installed in the `/opt` folder as default. Now, to launch the application, open up terminal and type:

```
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer
```

Also, if you are unable to find the application in the `/opt` directory, then type this command to find the file:

```
sudo find / -type f -iname teamviewer
```

`sudo` to be sure that it searches all directories.

The above command will give you the location of the teamviewer file. After you get the location, type:

```
/new/path/to/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer
```